# Hugo v0.55.x Deprecation Errors - ".File.BaseFileName" on zero object

Tags: hugo

I've been experimenting with finding a fix for a new deprecation error that occurs with Hugo version 0.55.5:

```
.File.BaseFileName on zero object. Wrap it in if or with: {{ with .File }}{{ .BaseFileName }}{{ end }}
```

The two affected snippets of code in question:

```
{{ $header := print "_header." .Lang }}
    {{ range where .Site.Pages "File.BaseFileName" $header }}
    {{ .Content }} 
    {{else}}
  {{ if .Site.GetPage "page" "_header.md" }}
    {{(.Site.GetPage "page" "_header.md").Content}}
  {{else}}
    <a class="baselink" href="{{.Site.BaseURL}}">{{.Site.Title}}</a>
  {{end}}
{{end}}
```

&& the footer:

```
{{ $footer := print "_footer." .Lang }}
{{ range where .Site.Pages "File.BaseFileName" $footer }}
  {{ .Content }}
{{else}}
  {{ if .Site.GetPage "page" "_footer.md" }}
    {{(.Site.GetPage "page" "_footer.md").Content}}
  {{end}}
{{end}}
```

I've been attempting different variations of wrapping those segments of code with `{{ with .File }}` as the error message suggests, but it isn't liking anything I've been coming up with. As an example, if I put that surrounding bit of code around the `{{ range ... }}` statement, I get the error: `can't evaluate field Site in type source.File`. If someone could assist in figuring out where `{{ with .File }}` should be placed, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error

> can't evaluate field Site in type source.File

Because the context changes when inside `with`. To fix it, wrap your code in a `{{ with .File }}` as you mentioned.

Then everywhere you're using `.Site`, replace it with `site`.

Then make sure you're using Hugo version 0.53.0 or higher, so that the `site` keyword is available.